# Interceptors in a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, interceptor

I'm not able to make interceptors work in my spring boot application.

What I've done so far is a annotation for methods:

```
@Inerithed
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({METHOD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Log {}
```

The interceptor itself:

```
@Interceptor
@Log
public class LogInterceptor {
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object logInterceptor(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        return ctx.proceed();
    }
}
```

Then in my class I'm using:

```
@Interceptors({LogInterceptor.class})
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Log
    public void compute() {}
}
```

But `LogInterceptor::logInterceptor()` method is never executed when I call `myService.compute()`.
What am I doing wrong?